# Changing coil voltage for Electric Relay - HF14FW/0XX-HSTF

Tags: relay

I have a controller board with [HF14FW/018-HSTF](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/193695/HONGFA/HF14FW/018-HSTFXXX.html) electric relay. It's not functioning now, so I need a new one, but apparently an 18 V version is not available anywhere.

How can I adjust the coil voltage, if I buy 12 V or 24 V versions? Or maybe there is an alternative model I can use, with similar characteristics?

Any help or advice is highly appreciated.

PS: It's from the water level controller for an espresso machine, if it matters.

Comment: I had a similar problem replacing a relay in my *ancient* oil burner system. That unit was installed in 1970 and they don't make relays for it, anymore. The voltage it used was literally unobtainium. However, the same manufacturer did make relays of the same form-factor and purpose at different voltages nearby what I needed. It turns out that relays are usually designed to work at 70% of their rating and a nearby relay voltage I could get engages just fine. So I didn't need to worry too much. The furnace is working fine today with the "wrong" relay in it. You could try 24 V there. Might work.

Comment: Can you post a picture of your exact relay? With the layout for the pins. Technically, any 18V 20+A relay is compatible, if you're willing to solder it on with wires. But getting the correct layout saves time.

Comment: To supplement jonk's comment: as you consider possible replacement replay parts, look at the replacement relay's "pull-in voltage" spec (a.k.a., pick-up voltage, must operate voltage).  The relay's switch will actuate for any coil voltage between the stated pick-up voltage and the coil's rated voltage.  For example, if the specified pick-up voltage is 16 VDC and the coil's rated voltage is 24 VDC, then any coil voltage between (16-24) VDC will actuate the switch.

Comment: Another suggestion would be to contact the manufacturer (Xiamen Hongfa Electroacoustic Co. Ltd., in China) and ask them to send you a sample part (or two!) that's an exact replacement. If they won't send you some sample parts, ask their marketing department to provide you the name of some distributors that sell Hongfa's products.  Sometimes, the hardest part about obtaining replacement parts is finding a company that sells the parts you want. Hongfa's website is https://www.hongfa.com.  If you scroll down to the bottom of the page you'll find a "CONTACT US" section.

Comment: @Mike - Just one thing to consider: You said that the relay is "*not functioning now*". Although a faulty relay is certainly possible, that symptom does not *necessarily* mean that the relay *itself* is faulty. Depending on your experience with a DMM, and your knowledge of how to stay safe with (what I assume to be) mains-powered equipment, then measuring across the relay's coil pins when it is supposed to be "on" would help to confirm/deny whether the relay itself is faulty. (To be clear: I'm not encouraging you to work on live equipment, if you're not confident about how to stay safe.)

Answer (score 2):

Short of magically coming up with a replacement, there's nothing that's ideal. You appear to have a "sensitive" coil unit nominally 620\$\Omega\$ coil resistance @23°C.

Using a 12V sensitive coil unit with a series 130\$\Omega\$ 1/4-W resistor will draw 50% more current so it could damage the driver or overload the power supply. A 24V one might sort-of work, but fail with a bit low mains voltage on a hot day (pick-up voltage increases as the coil warms), and would have shortened contact life.

Other similarly  rated substitutes such as Panasonic are typically much less sensitive in coil current so they would be much worse than the HF14FW/012-HSTF + 130\$\Omega\$ 1/4-W

There is one more-or less sure way, if you have a good set of tools and patience and can know enough to be able to take care to avoid possible safety issues, and that's to buy a replacement sensitive coil unit of any voltage and graft the new contacts (the part which will have worn out) onto the old coil. This kind of relay that meets VDE and not just the more slack UL specifications has a plastic pusher that works through a hole in a plastic barrier. That separation is critical to safety.

If the machine isn't too expensive, I'd be inclined to try the HF14FW/012-HSTF + 130Ω 1/4-W personally. Note, not the HF14FW/012-HSPTF